# Taxicab metric with open, closed unit ball, and unit sphere.

Tags: real-analysis

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the Taxicab metric is defined by $d(x,y) = |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2|.$ 
In this metric, describe/draw the open unit ball, closed unit ball, and the unit sphere which are based at the origin with radius $1$.

Here is my work:

Since it says this problem based at the origin,

Open unit ball is $B(0,1) = \{x \in M : d(x,0) < 1\}$ which means open ball with center origin and radius $1$.

Closed unit ball is $B[0,1] = \{x \in M : d(x,0) <= 1\}$

Unit sphere is $S(0,1) = \{x\in M : d(x,0) = 1\}$

But I'm not sure how to draw them. I draw a dotted circle for the open ball with center  $(0,0)\,$ and $r = 1$. But I doubt because I draw within negative quadrant. Like just a circle with $(0,0)\,$ and $r = 1$. I hope you understand my description....

Comment: I think I learned to call that the Manhattan metric? “Taxicab metric” seems like a bad match in some places, such as Boston and many old European cities.

Comment: @Harald: I’ve seen both terms, but *taxicab metric* is much more familiar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you know what the taxicab metric is? Find its definition and try to find lots of points in $\mathbb R^2$ that will have distance precisely $1$ from the origin. That will be the boundary of $B(0,1)$, and it will *not* look anything like a circle.

Comment: Then a rectangular

Comment: @therexists: In what orientation?

Comment: |
|
|
----------------------

Comment: Sorry I tried to draw what I drew. Um, (0,0) and x = 1 , y = 1

Comment: @therexists: But the point $\langle 1,1\rangle$ is $2$ units away from the origin, not $1$.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it.

Comment: @therexists: (You have to include `@Brian` somewhere in the comment if you want to be sure that I’ll see it.) I think that you need to go back and take a closer look at the definition of the taxicab metric. What is the distance (in that metric) between the points $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle x,y\rangle$?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the points on the coordinate axes (either $x=0$ or $y=0$). Then compute the points where $x=\pm y$. If you don't see it yet, choose some values for $x$ between zero and one and compute $y$ through
\begin{gather}
|y| = 1-|x|.
\end{gather}
Here, I used $x$ and $y$ as the two components of the vectors in $\mathbb R^2$.